# Flutter: How layout like spaceBetween of Tabbar

Tags: dart, flutter

```
    final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: 'a'),
    new Tab(text: 'b'),
    new Tab(text: 'c'),
    new Tab(text: 'd'),
    new Tab(text: 'e'),
  ];
```

then

```
    appBar: new AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: _barSearch(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: myTabs,
            labelColor: Color(0xffFF645C),
            labelStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            unselectedLabelStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
            unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff343434),
            indicatorColor: Color(0xffFF645C),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
          ),
        ),
```

It shows how I use tabbar.
But now, I find that my Tabbar layout is like to that of spaceAround.
[image]

But our project manager asked me to use spaceBetween.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever end up making this work?

Answer (score 3):

you should set your
isScrollable: false,

i hope it works for you .

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing Space-between in TabBar but here's my approach of achieving your goal:

1. I wrap tab to Align Widget since tabs is a list of Widget and do the corresponding changes. You can modify based on your need or even use Positioned Widget to achieve the same

   ```
    tabs: [

          Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,child: 
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
          ),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight,child: 
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
          ),
         ],
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`AppBar` Widget can be very restricting at times. Every time this degree of customization is required, you should prefer building this Widget separately and simply adding it under the `Scaffold`.

You can super easily achieve this result with the following lines of code:

```
final List<Widget> myTabs = <Widget>[
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
    child: new Tab(text: 'a'),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
    child: new Tab(text: 'b'),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
    child: new Tab(text: 'c'),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
    child: new Tab(text: 'd'),
  ),
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
    child: new Tab(text: 'e'),
  ),
];

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Center(child: Text('Coding24h')),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: myTabs,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In this way, you can get the fully customizing result you want without having AppBar's restrictions.